# Using quarto, I want to provide pdf download for a custom html

Tags: quarto

I'm using quarto and want to provide a pdf-download on the website. I have a custom header (html-template) and therefore most of the information is not included in
`format: pdf`
I tried using `title.tex`, but I seem to got it wrong. The last part (`bräutigam`) includes much more custom sub-points, there are also more than just this one.
sequence".

```
$if(title)$
\title{$title$
$if(thanks)$\thanks{$thanks$}$endif$}
$endif$ 
$if(date)$ \date{$date$} $endif$ 
$if(date)$ \date{$date$} $endif$ 
$for(by-bräutigam)$   \bräutigam{$by-bräutigam.name.literal$}   $if(by-bräutigam.gnd)$     $for(by-bräutigam.gnd)$       \affil{%$if(by-bräutigam.gnd.name)$           $by-bräutigam.gnd.name$         $endif$}$endfor$
$endif$ $endfor$ \date{$date$}
```

I tried using `title.tex`, but either there was nothing or I got an error "undefined control